# Korean language input issue on macOS Catalina

Tags: macbook-pro, keyboard, language

I have the Korean keyboard enabled on my new MacBook Pro (2020, macOS Catalina) and use <kbd>Command</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> to switch between the keyboards (English-Korean).

The problem is that, whenever I use the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key for a double consonant (e.g., ㅆ) in the 받침 position for Korean, the action automatically changes the input source to English and produces a capitalized English letter. Instead of getting 았, I'll be getting "아T".

Does anyone have suggestions to fix this issue? Thank you!

Comment: Do you have the box checked which makes caps lock the way to switch keyboards?

Comment: Thus far, I didn't have that caps lock box checked. Once I checked it, the problem described above indeed disappeared but, caps lock switching between keyboards interferes with my typing English. I had multiple Macs before and I never had an issue like this before. Is this a new thing?

Comment: I don't see this problem in my Catallina, so I think it must be something you have installed on your machine.  But why would using Caps Lock to switch interfere with typing English?  Do you use Caps Lock instead of the usual Shift to type single capital letters?

Comment: Not sure if there is something wrong with my keyboard. Yes, I tend to use the caps lock to type single capital letters.

Comment: Does your shift key also switch to Korean when you are using the US layout?

Comment: Nope. Only when I'm typing Korean.

Comment: I think your keyboard is OK then.  Which Korean IM are you using, 2-Set?

Comment: Yes. I am using 2 set.